# Aws Elastic Beanstalk (single docker) set jvm Xms and Xmx (JAVA_OPTS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, grails3

We are running our Grails 3 application (build on Spring Boot) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk singe docker container.

Our docker file looks like:

```
FROM java:8-jre

ADD build/libs/app-*.war app.war

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dgrails.env=prod","-Dserver.port=8080","-jar","/app.war"]
```

I'd like to increase jvm heap size which I can do simply by changing docker file:

```
FROM java:8-jre

ADD build/libs/app-*.war app.war

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xms1g", "Xmx2g","-Dgrails.env=prod","-Dserver.port=8080","-jar","/app.war"]
```

The problem starts when I run my app in several environments (with different machines and RAM sizes). I'd like to be able to configure it from AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I've been investigating several approaches but without any luck:

1. Use AWS EB Options

   - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html
   - didn't found how
2. Seting JAVA_OPTS

   - https://medium.com/@cl4r1ty/docker-spring-boot-and-java-opts-ba381c818fa2
   - but I cannot change docker run command in AWS EB

Is there any way how to set this?